# Connection refused when trying to debug nodejs application that requires babel/register

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, babeljs

So this is my launch.json file

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "se",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--require",
        "@babel/register",
        "${workspaceFolder}"
      ],
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And when I click on run without debugging, application starts normally.
This is the command, that visual studio code ran: `/usr/bin/node --require @babel/register /home/golobitch/progs/se`

But when I click on Start debugging, it runs following command: `/usr/bin/node --require @babel/register /home/tadejgolobic/progs/auth --inspect-brk=44800` and after 10s, I get error window, saying that "*Cannot connect to runtime process timeout after 10000ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:44800).*"

If I run above command in the terminal, program will start, but debugger will not. But if I reorder parameters, and write `--inspect-brk` immediately after `/usr/bin/node` then debugger will start, but the program will not (probably the same issue as in VSC, but I do not get any error).

So my question is, how to configure it, that debug will work?